# Problems with crs projection information when creating raster brick from netCDF file in R

Tags: r, spatial, netcdf, coordinate-systems

I'm working with Swiss meteo data stored in netCDF files. Example data are available [here](https://www.meteoswiss.admin.ch/home/climate/swiss-climate-in-detail/raeumliche-klimaanalysen.html).

After downloading and reading the data

```
download.file(url = "https://www.meteoswiss.admin.ch/content/dam/meteoswiss/de/Ungebundene-Seiten/Produkte/doc/tnorm9120.zip")
unzip("tnorm9120.zip")

filename <- "TnormM9120_ch01r.swiss.lv95_000001010000_000012010000.nc"

tnorm9120 <- nc_open(filename)
tnorm9120
```

I have file of this form:

```
File data-raw/tnorm9120/TnormM9120_ch01r.swiss.lv95_000001010000_000012010000.nc (NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC):

     5 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float swiss_lv95_coordinates[]   
            _FillValue: -1
            grid_mapping_name: Oblique Mercator (LV95 - CH1903+)
            longitude_of_projection_center: 7.43958333
            latitude_of_projection_center: 46.9524056
            false_easting: 2600000
            false_northing: 1200000
            inverse_flattening: 299.1528128
            semi_major_axis: 6377397.155
        double climatology_bounds[ncb,time]   
            units: months since 1991-01-01 00:00:00
            _FillValue: -1
        float TnormM9120[E,N,time]   
            units: degree
            _FillValue: -999.989990234375
            grid_mapping: swiss_lv95_coordinates
            coordinates: lon lat
            long_name: mean monthly temperature 1991-2020
            grid_name: ch01r.swiss.lv95
            version: v1.4
            prod_date: 2021-09-30 17:40:40
            cell_methods: time: mean within years time: mean over years
        float lon[E,N]   
            units: degrees_east
            _FillValue: NaN
            long_name: longitude coordinate
            standard_name: longitude
        float lat[E,N]   
            units: degrees_north
            _FillValue: NaN
            long_name: latitude coordinate
            standard_name: latitude

     4 dimensions:
        ncb  Size:2 
            long_name: ncb
        time  Size:12   *** is unlimited *** 
            units: months since 1991-01-01 00:00:00
            long_name: time
            axis: T
            calendar: standard
            climatology: climatology_bounds
        E  Size:370 
            units: meters_east
            long_name: swiss easting (lv95)
            standard_name: projection x coordinate
        N  Size:240 
            units: meters_north
            long_name: swiss northing (lv95)
            standard_name: projection y coordinate

    3 global attributes:
        Conventions: CF-1.6
        institution: Federal Office of Meteorology and Climatology MeteoSwiss
        References: Frei C., 2014: Interpolation of temperatures in a mountainous region using nonlinear profiles and non-Euclidean distances. Int. J. Climatol., 34, 1585-1605. DOI: 10.1002/joc.3786.
```

I was trying to set up the coordinate system (which should be [EPSG:2056](https://epsg.io/2056)) on the raster brick using:

```
b <- brick(filename, crs = st_crs(2056)$proj4string)
```

However that gives me the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In .getCRSfromGridMap4(atts) : cannot process these parts of the crs:
_FillValue=-1
longitude_of_projection_center=7.43958333
latitude_of_projection_center=46.9524056
2: In .getCRSfromGridMap4(atts) : cannot create a valid crs
grid_mapping_name; false_easting; false_northing; scale_factor_at_projection_origin; scale_factor_at_central_meridian; standard_parallel; standard_parallel1; standard_parallel2; longitude_of_central_meridian; longitude_of_projection_origin; latitude_of_projection_origin; straight_vertical_longitude_from_pole; longitude_of_prime_meridian; semi_major_axis; semi_minor_axis; inverse_flattening; earth_radius; +proj; +x_0; +y_0; +k_0; +k_0; +lat_1; +lat_1; +lat_2; +lon_0; +lon_0; +lat_0; +lon_0; +pm; +a; +b; +rf; +a
```

I tried other ways of setting up CRS but that either resulted in error or the same warnings as above. Is there any way around it?

**Update:** alternative attempts are documented in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/RPanczak/959f36d173f949304f26a5d7fe09f844).

Odly enough when I tried plotting this data in QGIS I ended up with the country upside down o_O

[image]

Comment: If you're using package {terra}, mind that setting `crs` does not actually transform the data - which can be done with `project`: https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/project.html

Comment: I removed the (new) crs tag, because CRS can mean much more than a coordinate reference system.

Comment: Thanks @I_O. If crs is known would `crs(terra) <- "epsg:2056"` be the solution to fix it?

Comment: @radek: I'm afraid not (not having tested it yet), it should be two steps: (1) Assign the original CRS (the NCD used in the original post seemed to bear no CRS - at least not when imported by `terra::rast`, so I assumed it from the "bessel" keyword in the object summary. I assigned the putative original CRS with `terra::crs(some_raster) <- 'epsg:nnnn'`, so that terra knows which CRS to project *from*. (2) Use `terra::project(some_raster,'epsg:mmmm'` to project *to* the target CRS. --- Unfortunately I couldn't get the original example to work, either. Probably issue with `gdalwarp`

Answer (score 1):

We are the authors of these NetCDF files at MeteoSwiss. If you can direct us how to format the crs info stored in the NetCDF grid mapping variable, please get back to us. We tried to follow the CF-convention and it works for the old swiss (LV03/CH1903) projection and regular lon/lat. But it seems to fail for the new swiss (LV95/CH1903+) in your application.

We're happy to post test files in case you find out what goes wrong in the CRS.

Can you confirm that you can read the CRS stored in our previous (LV03/ch1903) files, since we never got any complaint on these:
ftp://ftp.cscs.ch/out/stockli/swisscors/TminM_ch01r.swisscors_201903010000_201903010000.nc

Cheers
Reto

Comment: many thanks for picking it up @reto-stöckli I rerun all the R solutions from the gist i shared and unfortunately it doesn't seem that the LV03 CRS gets picked up correctly either :/ I also am not sure what the correct format would be to apply there.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. Since the grid_mapping attribute could host a dozillion of attributes, could you eventually find out which ones are missing to have a complete description of the swiss metric coordinate system (which is nothing fancy by itself, it is an orthogonal projection with a sphere description and a true north/east, and all this information is in the file).